# shell script error while running .sql file

Tags: oracle, shell

While calling .sql file from shell script required data is retrieved but after completion - below errors are shown.

```
WHENEVER:  not found.
SET:  not found.
SET:  not found.
SET:  not found.
```

run command

```
sqlplus -s user/pasd@oracle_sid @file.sql
```

file.sql

```
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT 1
SET TERMOUT   OFF
SET ECHO      OFF
SET EMBEDDED  ON
SET FEEDBACK  OFF
SET HEADING   OFF

spool file.log
select 'xyz' from dual;

spool off;
exit;
```

Comment: where's the shell script?

Comment: in .sh sqlplus -s user/pasd@oracle_sid @file.sql

Comment: that's it? nothing else?

Comment: Do you have a `login.sql` (if it's only affecting you) or `glogin.sql` (if it affcts others on your host)? Might be worth checking if the errors are coming from that, or if it has an incomplete command that's having a knock-on on your script. If your environment or shell script sets `$SQLPATH` it might be picking up a file you don't expect.